# How do I place files of JavaBridge for my PHP Project?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I'm here trying to deal with how to place the JavaBridge package that I downloaded, into my PHP project to start using its classes contained (for example to require into my php file the java.inc class). I have been trying to suit it for my application project. I will be pending for any response from you all! beforehand I thank you for your help!

Comment: Unless you are very experienced don’t mix languages like this.  There may be a lot of pain down that path.  What is the actual problem that you think this will solve?

Comment: Hi @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, ok I got your idea, but what I'm trying to solve is generate a PDF Report from Jaspersoft Studio that I made, and from a library from PHP I'm not able to do it, because it generates me a lot of errors.